# Add MSDN subscribers to Visual Studio Team Services account

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Can a MSDN Visual Studio Professional subscriber be added as user to two or more TFS and/or VSTS accounts? I am setting up our own VSTS account and I want to add a contractor as a user with MSDN VS Professional subscription but he also uses it to access his company's TFS. Thanks.

This [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/add-users-team-project?view=vsts) does not answer my question explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some subscriptions are provided through the MPN (Microsoft Partner Network) and most of these are only allowed to be used for company internal product development. These rules are pretty strict, they can never be used by external people to develop software for you or to access your systems.

> ### Visual Studio Subscriptions through Microsoft Partner Network(MPN)
>
> Visual Studio subscriptions offered through the Microsoft Partner Network cannot be used for direct revenue-generating
>   activities, such as providing consulting services, customizing a packaged application for a specific customer, or building a
>   custom application for a customer, for a fee.
>
> <sup>https://assets.microsoft.com/cs-cz/MPN-MAPS-Product-Usage-Guide.pdf</sup>

If the external partner has a "retail" MSDN subscription they may use this to access any VSTS account. They cannot use it to access a TFS server unless it's owned by their own organisation.

> These same Visual Studio subscribers
>   are granted a Team Foundation Server 2018 User CAL to be used within their organization (it is not valid for use of
>   Team Foundation Server acquired by a different organization)
>
> <sup>https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Visual-Studio-2018-Licensing-Whitepaper-November-2017.pdf</sup>

The owning organisation of a Team Foundation Server must still purchase a CAL or a VSTS Basic User for each external party accessing their TFS server:

> External contractors with Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription, Visual Studio Enterprise – annual, Visual Studio Enterprise –
>   monthly, MSDN Platforms, or Visual Studio Test Professional Subscription subscriptions supplied by their organization can
>   also access these features in Team Foundation Servers running at other organizations. However, a Team Foundation Server
>   CAL purchased by the organization that licensed the Team Foundation Server must be assigned to each of these users.
>
> <sup>https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Visual-Studio-2018-Licensing-Whitepaper-November-2017.pdf</sup>

You can satisfy the TFS CAL requirement using a VSTS Basic user:

> Buy VSTS for TFS CALs. When you buy VSTS users (starting at $6/month), those same users have a TFS CAL and can connect to any TFS in your organization. If those users also need TFS extensions like Test Manager or Package Management, or if you need additional Private Pipelines for your team, you can purchase these through the Visual Studio Marketplace. All VSTS charges are month-to-month. See detailed instructions.
>
> <sup>https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/</sup>

Visual Studio Team Services doesn't have this restriction:

> ### Visual Studio Team Services Benefits for Visual Studio Subscribers
>
> All Visual Studio subscribers (standard and cloud) who have activated their subscription can create or join any Visual
>   Studio Team Services account at no additional charge. Additional extensions are also available to Visual Studio subscribers
>   at no extra charge (table with extensions provided per subscription type).
>
> <sup>https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Visual-Studio-2018-Licensing-Whitepaper-November-2017.pdf</sup>

So it all boils down to:

- Is the subscription provided through MPN?

  - **If yes, they cannot use that license to access VSTS or TFS in another organisation nor use it to develop software for these other organisations.**
  - If no... continue:
- What are you accessing?

  - VSTS: They can use the license to develop software and to access any VSTS account.
  - TFS: They can use the license to develop software but **not** access **your** TFS server without a CAL/VSTS Basic User.
- Accessing TFS: Have you purchased and assigned a CAL/VSTS Basic User

  - VSTS Basic user: They can assess your VSTS account **and** they can access your TFS server.
  - TFS CAL: They can access your TFS Server

The easiest and in most cases the cheapest license for these external parties is the VSTS Basic User option, especially since these can get reassigned at any time and can be ended every month. Or to switch to VSTS, where all non-MPN-subscribers will be allowed to access and develop software for your organisation without additional administration or costs.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.